# How to upgrade Julia to v0.5.0?

Tags: upgrade, julia

now that they release v0.5.0 the question is how can I upgrade from 0.4.6 to 0.5.0 without loosing all my packages? is there even a way. Or if there is no easy way, how have people done it? What is the best way to do it?

Other question is, is it worth it or do I need to upgrade? What are the benefits or why I should not upgrade (yet)? Is there problems with Atom and other packages?

Yes there is quest same question already, but it is for older version and I thought if something has changed on upgrading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go into your .julia/v0.4 folder and copy the REQUIRE file to the v0.5 folder. Then when you `Pkg.update()` your packages should automatically install.

There are very many upgrades (broadcast syntax, arraypoclypse, string changes, etc.), and many packages may stop supporting v0.4 for this reason. I would recommend you start upgrading soon. Juno has already released its v0.5 version, so when you update it should be compatible.

Comment: I did like that...Well Atom didn't like new version. I downloaded the new julia exe and installed and copy the REQUIRE file and pkg.update(). Now I try to reinstall Atom.

Comment: You may need to update your Julia path to get Juno/Atom to find the new version.

Comment: If you mean in Atom julia-client package settings, I did that. Doesn't work still. It finds Julia, but I get this error : "WARNING: Module Juno with uuid 11760700770693 is missing from the cache.
This may mean module Juno does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does." That it says to make pkg.update(), but it wound work

Comment: It looks like `Pkg.update()` didn't completely resolve the dependencies and install the Juno.jl package. If you Pkg.status() do you see Juno.jl? If not, do a `Pkg.add("Juno")` and then a `Pkg.update()`. This is probably handled best [in a chat](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) though.

Comment: For future reference, this issue is related to [this](https://github.com/JunoLab/uber-juno/issues/15) which was solved by `using Atom` from the REPL.